# Receive ProcessExit/Stop event from Task Manager for a hidden WindowsForm

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi, win32-process

I have tried solving this, but the only solution was to make a window that is visible to the user (even making it 0x0 still makes it visible in the Alt-Tab switcher).

When I mean hidden, I want it hidden from Alt-Tab, Win-Tab, Ctrl-Tab, the Taskbar, and the "Apps" section of Task Manager.

Any workaround? I only need to detect an unexpected stop from Task Manager, but I need a window to receive events from `SetWinEventHook()`.

Comment: The voting is because it is unclear as to what your question is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a catch-22. You need a window to receive WinEvents. You could create a [message-only window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#message_only) for that, which is hidden from the system.

But, hiding a window from the system also means hiding it from Task Manager.  If Task Manager doesn't see a visible window (doesn't show it in "Apps"), it will not try to close the window gracefully, it will just kill the process abortively, and there is no signal sent to the process when that happens.

To get a graceful close, you can't hide the window from the system, but then you have to accept the other side effects that go along with it.

The only option I can think of in this situation is to create a separate process that monitors your main process. If the main process disappears unexpectedly, the watcher process can react accordingly. You could make the watcher be a service so non-admin users can't kill it in Task Manager.